# In request with join category table I got invalid ID of request table

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 8 making a request with join category table:

```
        $ads = Ad
            ::getByStatus($filterStatus)            
            ->where('ads.id', 2) // debug with main image
            ->getByCreatorId($filterUsersArray)
            ->getByTitle($filterText)
            ->getByAdType($filterAdType)
            ->leftJoin('ad_categories', 'ad_categories.ad_id', '=', 'ads.id')
            ->orderBy('ads.expire_date', 'desc')
//            ->distinct('ads.id')
            ->get();
```

I got invalid value for ‘id’, which appears id of all related categories.id fields.

How it can be fixed ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use eager load to load ad_categories relationship or use alias:

1. eager load way:

   ```
    $ads = Ad
            ::getByStatus($filterStatus)            
            ->where('ads.id', 2) // debug with main image
            ->getByCreatorId($filterUsersArray)
            ->getByTitle($filterText)
            ->getByAdType($filterAdType)
            ->with('ad_category') // eager load
            ->orderBy('ads.expire_date', 'desc')
            ->get();
   ```
2. alias way:

   ```
    $ads = Ad
            ::getByStatus($filterStatus)            
            ->where('ads.id', 2) // debug with main image
            ->getByCreatorId($filterUsersArray)
            ->getByTitle($filterText)
            ->getByAdType($filterAdType)
            ->leftJoin('ad_categories', 'ad_categories.ad_id', '=', 'ads.id')
            ->selectRaw('ad_categories.id as categoryId, ad_categories.ad_id, ads.*') // select alias
            ->orderBy('ads.expire_date', 'desc')
            ->get();
   ```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please provide  links to related documents?

Comment: eager loading: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading , select raw: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions